# Exclude line numbers from margin width

Tags: spacing, margins, double-sided, marginpar, line-numbering

I am using the lineno package to add linenumbers on my twosided document. However, I have a restriction to leave a margin of 2.5cm inner and 4cm outer margin. This has to be completely free space.

But the line numbers of the lineno package are being added into both those margins.

1. Can I somehow specify that the linenumbers are added to the document body instead of the margin?
2. If not, how do I set the margin of the document so that the correct amount of space is free of content?

I thought about just adding the line number width to the margin, but because the line numbers are always on the left margin on even and odd pages, I would have to alternate this additional margin for my twosided document.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
    tmargin=2.5cm,
    bmargin=2.5cm,
    lmargin=4cm,
    rmargin=2.5cm,
    nomarginpar,
    showframe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This screenshot illustrates my problem:

[image: margins]

The orange line shows how far the 4cm / 2.5cm go, the blue line shows how they should actually be. The line numbers should be further to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\makeLineNumber` and give more room to the left margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
    tmargin=2.5cm,
    bmargin=2.5cm,
    lmargin=5cm,
    rmargin=2.5cm,
    nomarginpar,
    headheight=14.5pt,
    heightrounded,
    showframe}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\makeLineNumber}{\llap{\linenumberfont\rlap{\LineNumber}\hspace{1cm}}}

\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\noindent% just to make a rule
\llap{\vrule height 1pt width 3.9cm\hskip1cm}%
\lipsum[1-6]

\noindent% just to make a rule
\llap{\vrule height 1pt width 2.4cm\hskip1cm}%
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

The two rules are just 1mm short so that we can see the measurement is accurate. I added a setting for `headheight` and also `heightrounded`; the first is required by `fancyhdr`, the second makes the text height contain an integer number of lines.

### Top of page 1

[image]

### Top of page 2

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. While the left margin is correct now on both pages, the right one now is too wide. See this screenshot: http://oi40.tinypic.com/351a721.jpg Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @atticae I get 4cm on the odd pages and 2.5 on the even pages. If you want to fix also the opposite margin, just tell it to `geometry`.

Comment: I also get those values on the left (not inner) margin, as its supposed to be. But the right (not outer) margin is wrong. I can't fix that via geometry because I can only change outer and inner margin, not left and right on both odd and even pages.

Comment: @atticae Sorry, but I don't understand

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I need the inner margin to be 4cm, the outer to be 2.5cm. Your fix helps me get the left side of each page (where line numbers are) correct, but now the right side of each page is wrong. (see the measurements on the right in the screenshot in my previous comment).

Comment: @atticae Check now

Comment: Its better now, but still not correct. I checked the PDF page width and apparently its not 21cm wide (as a4paper should be), but ~21,5cm. I have no idea why? Those additional 0.5cm are now still added to the right margin. I added a \vrule to the right margin to illustrate it: http://pastebin.com/wCN4AhAN

Comment: @atticae I get exactly A4 paper. It may depend on how you produce the PDF: 21.59cm is exactly the width of US letter paper.

Comment: Wow, you were right. I changed from "dvips + ps2pdf" to "Asymptote + PdfLatex" and now everything is perfect. Never thought that would matter. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> but because the line numbers are always on the left margin on even and odd pages

The assumption is not true. You can use the `switch` option of the `lineno` package. See [Line numbers on different margins in two-sided document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146661/line-numbers-on-different-margins-in-two-sided-document) for a MWE.

Comment: I am aware of that. I actually want them to be always on the left side. By "always" I was just referring to my document.