# Line numbers on different margins in two-sided document

Tags: margins, double-sided, line-numbering

I'm using the `lineno` package to print line numbers in my two-sided document, but they are always printed in the left margin.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I load `lineno` with the option `right`

```
\usepackage[right]{lineno}
```

they all are printed in the right margin

[image]

What I would like to do is to print line numbers in the right margin in odd pages and in the left margin in even pages, but I haven't been able to find an option to achieve this.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `switch` option:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Was it so simple...? I tried with manual `\switchlinenumbers` with no luck! Thank you. BTW: you can suggest this answer in this thread as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146587/31910

Comment: @Sterry. You're welcome. I answered also the other thread.

Comment: Upvoted there, too.