# ConTeXt: Line numbers in different margins in doublesided document

Tags: margins, context, double-sided, line-numbering

I'm numbering my lines in a double-sided ConTeXt Mkiv document like so:

```
\usemodule[ipsum]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext
\startlinenumbering
\ipsum
\ipsum
\ipsum
\ipsum
\ipsum
\ipsum
\stoplinenumbering
\stoptext
```

They are always put in the left margin, no matter if I'm on a left or right page. Is there a way to put always put them into the inner or outer margin instead? (I'm basically asking the same question as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146661/line-numbers-on-different-margins-in-two-sided-document) for ConTeXt)

Comment: Add `\setuplinenumbering[location=outer]` place the numbers in the outer margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move the line numbers in the outer margin you have to change the value of the `location` with the `\setuplinenumbering` command.

```
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\setuplinenumbering[location=outer]

\starttext

\startlinenumbering
\dorecurse{5}{\samplefile{lorem}}
\stoplinenumbering

\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! :-) Is there any documentation on this? If I remember correctly, both PRAGMA's Reference Manual and the context garden wiki only mention "inmargin" and "intext" as options for location, and I think both resulted in the number being in the left margin...

Comment: You find a (nearly) complete list of all options for each command in the [command reference](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf).